# Can I start extracting a 7z file while downloading?

Tags: 7-zip, 7za

I have a very big 7z file that I am downloading. Extracting these kind of files also take a lot of time for me. Is it possible to start extracting them while still downloading? Like you can do with movies which you can start watching them while downloading if you download in sequential order.

Extra info since comments asked: I am on Ubuntu 20.04, so files being open/closed not an actual issue.

Also, If I try it, it starts (probably because I already downloaded the first and last parts which contains file structure etc) but since it's a torrent download that creates the files on disk fully (maybe with 00 for the not-yet-downloaded parts), I asked to know if the extracted files might be corrupted or something. So "it works" but I am asking to know even though I have downloaded 80%, starting the extraction would create corrupted files (before hitting 80%).

If I rephrase the question: Is 7z files (except the first and last meta parts) laid out sequentially?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The file has not properly closed. So trying to use it before initially closing it will not work.

Comment: Well, it starts (probably because I already downloaded the first and last parts which contains file structure etc) but since it's a torrent download that creates the files on disk fully (maybe with 00 for the not-yet-downloaded parts), I asked to know if the extracted files might be corrupted or something. So "it works" but I am asking to know even though I have downloaded 80%, starting the extraction would create corrupted files (before hitting 80%).

Comment: The extraction would fail due to checksum error.

Comment: So if it doesn't fail, then it means it's OK? Because I have started extracting when the download was at 90% and it completed while the extraction was at 50%. So it must be fine since it haven't seen any checksum error or something.

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer but it appears to me that YES, they are.  If you [look at the file format](https://www.romvault.com/Understanding7z.pdf) which I can only assume that not a single person here has done.. you will see the file layout and how decompression works.  You would need to be a c/c++ programmer and hack the 7z exe to ignore the checksum until the end.  It looks possible but the pdf I reference is very complicated and I gave up when my eyes crossed.